# Derivation of $ \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma $

Tags: statistics

Near the last step for deriving the unbiasness check of $\hat{\sigma}$, we come to a point where

$$ = \frac{1}{n} \bigg(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma + \mu^2   
-n (\frac{\sigma}{n} + \mu^2 ) \bigg) 
$$

where $\mu,\sigma$ are usual suspects, but then derivation jumps to

$$\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma$$

I am not sure how this is obtained, I can get to

$$ =  \sigma + \mu^2 - \sigma - n\mu^2
$$

and

$$ =  \mu^2  - n\mu^2
$$

So how do we get to a statement with $\sigma$ in it? Any ideas? An example of this derivation can be found in Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications by Larsen, page 315.

[image]

Comment: Ok, then it is ok, the summation in the last step is only over $\sigma$ and $\mu^2$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 equalities that are justified as follows.

1st. Definition of $\hat{\sigma}^2$.

2nd. Expansion of $(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$.

3rd. You have that $$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i^2-2Y_i\bar{Y}+\bar{Y}^2)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_i^2\right)-2\bar{Y}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\right)+\frac{1}{n}\cdot n \cdot \bar{Y}^2\\&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_i^2\right)-2\bar{Y}^2+\bar{Y}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_i^2\right)-\bar{Y}^2\end{align*}$$ 
So $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i^2-2Y_i\bar{Y}+\bar{Y}^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_i^2\right)-n\bar{Y}^2$$ and from now on the term $-n\bar{Y}^2$ is out of the summation! So here is your problem. The expectation is over both terms, the factor $\frac{1}{n}$ is for both terms, but the summation is only over the first term $Y_i^2$.

4th. Interchange of Summation and Expectation.

5th. Plugging in that $E[Y_i^2]=Var(Y_i)+E[Y_i]^2$ by the definition of variance and that $E[\bar{Y}^2]=Var(\bar{Y})+E[\bar{Y}]^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$.

6th. Calculate the summation as above.

Comment: Yeah my brain was fried man.. I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, not your fault. I have struggled many times with the statistics books for their loose derivations of complicated formulas

Answer (score 1):

Your summation over $i$ is independent of $i$ (you have only $\sigma$). So the sum is equal to $n\cdot \sigma$ since you practically add up $\sigma$ $n$ times (i.e. for each $1\le i\le n$ you add up $\sigma$: $$\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sigma^2+\mu^2\right)-\sigma^2-n\mu^2 \right)=\frac{1}{n}\left(n\cdot \sigma^2+n\mu^2-\sigma^2-n\mu^2 \right)=\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$$

Comment: Wait, the summation applies to all the terms doesn't it? To $\sigma$, as well as $\mu$.

Comment: I corrected it. It applies only to $\sigma$ and the first $\mu^2$. I do not have the derivation of the equation in front of me, but knowing the result, that has to be it

Comment: Please check it yourself, or post a link so that I can check it. But I am pretty sure, that it is as above. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the derivation, I think at some point $n\bar{Y}$ is taken out of the summation, but this is not clear in the notation...

Comment: Ok, take it step by step. There are 6 $"="$ signs. Which are not ok? First is definition, the 6th we explained.